# Xml Data Binding 2001 missing schema on W3

Tags: c#, xml, delphi

How do I get the Data binding schema for the following code?
`<objectModel xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="xsd/objectmodel.xsd">`
I cant find anything online about that.

Comment: See following : https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/

Answer (score 0):

There is no schema document for this namespace, because it is not needed. The declarations for attributes in this namespace (such as `xsi:type` and `xsi:nil`) are baked in to every schema processor and cannot be varied.

What are you trying to achieve, and what problem are you encountering?